# Reducing the username length limit on Redhat

Tags: rhel, users

I want to reduce the username length limit from 32 to 30. Is it possible to configure the limit?

When I try to useradd on RHEL, it is allowing to create user up to 32 characters. I want to shorten the length to 30 bytes to restrict user creation to max of 30 bytes length. I see its possible on AIX platform. But I could not find way on how to configure on redhat RHEL servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's hard-coded in the `useradd` binary.

From the source of `shadow-utils-4.6-7.el8` (the package which provides `/usr/sbin/useradd`):

```
./lib/defines.h:

/* Maximum length of usernames */
#ifdef HAVE_UTMPX_H
# include <utmpx.h>
# define USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH (sizeof (((struct utmpx *)NULL)->ut_user))
#else
# include <utmp.h>
# ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_USER
#  define USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH (sizeof (((struct utmp *)NULL)->ut_user))
# else
#  ifdef HAVE_STRUCT_UTMP_UT_NAME
#   define USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH (sizeof (((struct utmp *)NULL)->ut_name))
#  else
#   define USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH 32
#  endif
# endif
#endif
```

(that `utmp->ut_user` field is 32 bytes, too)

```
libmisc/chkname.c:

bool is_valid_user_name (const char *name)
{
        /*
         * User names are limited by whatever utmp can
         * handle.
         */
        if (strlen (name) > USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH) {
                return false;
        }

        return is_valid_name (name);
}
```

Of course, nobody stops you from writing a wrapper which enforces your usernames policy.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!